# Fade in Text Animation does not appear at all

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, typescript

I want to create a text animation that fades in when the user scrolls down to the desired section. I am trying to recreate this example - https://codepen.io/alvarotrigo/pen/ExvqdNa - in React with inline styling and I dont know why its not working. Can anyone help out and say where my error is?

I suspect I did not correctly declare my styles?

```
import React from 'react';

const styles = {
    body: {
        padding: '0px',
        margin: '0px',
        height: '100vh',
        display: 'flex',
        flexDirection: 'column',
        justifyContent: 'center',
        alignItems: 'center',
    },

    h1: {
        fontFamily: 'Montserrat Medium',
        maxWdth: '40ch',
        textAlign: 'center',
        transform: 'scale(0.94)',
        animation: 'scale 3s forwards cubic-bezier(0.5, 1, 0.89, 1)',
    },
    '@keyframes scale': {
        '100%': {
            transform: 'scale(1)',
        },
    },

    span: {
        display: 'inline-block',
        opacity: 0,
        filter: 'blur(4px)',
    },

    'span:nth-child(1)': {
        animation: 'fade-in 0.8s 0.1s forwards cubic-bezier(0.11, 0, 0.5, 0)',
    },

    'span:nth-child(2)': {
        animation: 'fade-in 0.8s 0.2s forwards cubic-bezier(0.11, 0, 0.5, 0)',
    },

    'span:nth-child(3)': {
        animation: 'fade-in 0.8s 0.3s forwards cubic-bezier(0.11, 0, 0.5, 0)',
    },

    'span:nth-child(4)': {
        animation: 'fade-in 0.8s 0.4s forwards cubic-bezier(0.11, 0, 0.5, 0)',
    },

    'span:nth-child(5)': {
        animation: 'fade-in 0.8s 0.5s forwards cubic-bezier(0.11, 0, 0.5, 0)',
    },

    'span:nth-child(6)': {
        animation: 'fade-in 0.8s 0.6s forwards cubic-bezier(0.11, 0, 0.5, 0)',
    },

    'span:nth-child(7)': {
        animation: 'fade-in 0.8s 0.7s forwards cubic-bezier(0.11, 0, 0.5, 0)',
    },

    'span:nth-child(8)': {
        animation: 'fade-in 0.8s 0.8s forwards cubic-bezier(0.11, 0, 0.5, 0)',
    },

    'span:nth-child(9)': {
        animation: 'fade-in 0.8s 0.9s forwards cubic-bezier(0.11, 0, 0.5, 0)',
    },

    'span:nth-child(10)': {
        animation: 'fade-in 0.8s 1s forwards cubic-bezier(0.11, 0, 0.5, 0)',
    },

    'span:nth-child(11)': {
        animation: 'fade-in 0.8s 1.1s forwards cubic-bezier(0.11, 0, 0.5, 0)',
    },

    'span:nth-child(12)': {
        animation: 'fade-in 0.8s 1.2s forwards cubic-bezier(0.11, 0, 0.5, 0)',
    },

    'span:nth-child(13)': {
        animation: 'fade-in 0.8s 1.3s forwards cubic-bezier(0.11, 0, 0.5, 0)',
    },

    'span:nth-child(14)': {
        animation: 'fade-in 0.8s 1.4s forwards cubic-bezier(0.11, 0, 0.5, 0)',
    },

    'span:nth-child(15)': {
        animation: 'fade-in 0.8s 1.5s forwards cubic-bezier(0.11, 0, 0.5, 0)',
    },

    'span:nth-child(16)': {
        animation: 'fade-in 0.8s 1.6s forwards cubic-bezier(0.11, 0, 0.5, 0)',
    },

    'span:nth-child(17)': {
        animation: 'fade-in 0.8s 1.7s forwards cubic-bezier(0.11, 0, 0.5, 0)',
    },
    'span:nth-child(18)': {
        animation: 'fade-in 0.8s 1.8s forwards cubic-bezier(0.11, 0, 0.5, 0)',
    },

    '@keyframes fade-in': {
        '100%': {
            opacity: 1,
            filter: 'blur(0)',
        },
    },
};

function TextAnimation() {
    return (
        <>
            <h1 style={styles.h1}>
                <span style={styles.span}>
                    <span style={styles['span:nth-child(1)']}>There</span>
                    <span style={styles['span:nth-child(2)']}>are</span>
                    <span style={styles['span:nth-child(3)']}>no</span>
                    <span style={styles['span:nth-child(4)']}>limits</span>
                    <span style={styles['span:nth-child(5)']}>to</span>
                    <span style={styles['span:nth-child(6)']}>what</span>
                    <span style={styles['span:nth-child(7)']}>you</span>
                    <span style={styles['span:nth-child(8)']}>can</span>
                    <span style={styles['span:nth-child(9)']}>accomplish,</span>
                    <span style={styles['span:nth-child(10)']}>except</span>
                    <span style={styles['span:nth-child(11)']}>the</span>
                    <span style={styles['span:nth-child(12)']}>limits</span>
                    <span style={styles['span:nth-child(13)']}>you</span>
                    <span style={styles['span:nth-child(14)']}>place</span>
                    <span style={styles['span:nth-child(15)']}>on</span>
                    <span style={styles['span:nth-child(16)']}>your</span>
                    <span style={styles['span:nth-child(17)']}>own</span>
                    <span style={styles['span:nth-child(18)']}>thinking.</span>
                </span>
            </h1>
        </>
    );
}

export { TextAnimation };
```

Comment: forwards may be the issue ... try using the correct animation direction. Hmmm that's odd. Forwards doesn't look valid. Yet it works in that codepan

Comment: hmm I removed forwards but still not working :/

Comment: To create animations, it is better to use plain CSS or CSS in JS library like `styled-components`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I reproduced the **codepen** example with `styled-components` and made this more custom,  when the sentence length changes you don't need to add or delete an extra pseudo-class each time. And this approach without any **innerHTML** injection.

#### TextAnimation.tsx

```js
import styled, { keyframes } from 'styled-components';

const fadeIn = keyframes`
100% {
    opacity: 1;
    filter: blur(0);
  }
`;

const H1Style = styled.h1`
  max-width: 500px;
  display: flex;
  gap: 0.5rem;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: center;
`;

const ChunksStyle = styled.span<{ order: number }>`
  display: inline-block;
  color: aliceblue;
  opacity: 0;
  filter: blur(4px);
  animation: ${fadeIn} 0.8s forwards cubic-bezier(0.11, 0, 0.5, 0);
  animation-delay: ${props => `${props.order}s`};
`;

const TextAnimation = ({ text }: { text: string }) => {
  const words = text.split(' ');

  const chunks = words.map((word, index) => {
    // index + 1 - our index start from 1
    // 10 - number of decimal seconds in one second
    const count = (index + 1) / 10;

    return (
      <ChunksStyle key={index} order={count}>
        {word}
      </ChunksStyle>
    );
  });

  return <H1Style>{chunks}</H1Style>;
};
```

#### App.tsx

```js
import "./styles.css";
import { TextAnimation } from './TextAnimation';

export default function App() {
  const text =
    'There are no limits to what you can accomplish, except the limits you place on your own thinking.';
  return (
    <>
      <TextAnimation text={text} />
    </>
  );
}
```

[image: Edit dazziling-code]

Comment: Thanks! I suppose if one want to use without libraries like styled-components its too much of a hassle

Answer (score 0):

i defined your keyframes as following, and removed them from the styles object (since they were never used anyway).

```
const fadeIn = `
    @-webkit-keyframes fade-in { 
        0% { 
            opacity: 0;
            filter: blur(4px);
        } 

        100% { 
            opacity: 1; 
            filter: blur(0); 
        } 
    } 
    `;
const scale = `
    @-webkit-keyframes scale {
         0% {
            transform: scale(0) 
        } 100% {
            transform: scale(1) 
        } 
    } `;
```

Now that allows you to solve the issue of not having the keyframes in your document by simply adding the following above the return of the `TextAnimation` component:

```
const style = document.createElement("style");
style.innerHTML = `${fadeIn} ${scale}`;
document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(style);
```

Finally you need to remove the default styling (of `opacity` and `filter`) regarding the spans (since we moved those to the keyframes themselves). span in `styles` now looks like this:

```
span: {
    display: "inline-block",
},
```

Now when rendering `TextAnimation`, it should work.
Complete code:

```
const styles = {
    body: {
        padding: "0px",
        margin: "0px",
        height: "100vh",
        display: "flex",
        flexDirection: "column",
        justifyContent: "center",
        alignItems: "center",
    },

    h1: {
        fontFamily: "Montserrat Medium",
        maxWdth: "40ch",
        textAlign: "center"
        transform: "scale(0.94)",
        animation: "scale 3s forwards cubic-bezier(0.5, 1, 0.89, 1)",
    },

    span: {
        display: "inline-block",
    },

    "span:nth-child(1)": {
        animation: "fade-in 0.8s 0.1s forwards cubic-bezier(0.11, 0, 0.5, 0)",
    },

    "span:nth-child(2)": {
        animation: "fade-in 0.8s 0.2s forwards cubic-bezier(0.11, 0, 0.5, 0)",
    },

    "span:nth-child(3)": {
        animation: "fade-in 0.8s 0.3s forwards cubic-bezier(0.11, 0, 0.5, 0)",
    },

    "span:nth-child(4)": {
        animation: "fade-in 0.8s 0.4s forwards cubic-bezier(0.11, 0, 0.5, 0)",
    },

    "span:nth-child(5)": {
        animation: "fade-in 0.8s 0.5s forwards cubic-bezier(0.11, 0, 0.5, 0)",
    },

    "span:nth-child(6)": {
        animation: "fade-in 0.8s 0.6s forwards cubic-bezier(0.11, 0, 0.5, 0)",
    },

    "span:nth-child(7)": {
        animation: "fade-in 0.8s 0.7s forwards cubic-bezier(0.11, 0, 0.5, 0)",
    },

    "span:nth-child(8)": {
        animation: "fade-in 0.8s 0.8s forwards cubic-bezier(0.11, 0, 0.5, 0)",
    },

    "span:nth-child(9)": {
        animation: "fade-in 0.8s 0.9s forwards cubic-bezier(0.11, 0, 0.5, 0)",
    },

    "span:nth-child(10)": {
        animation: "fade-in 0.8s 1s forwards cubic-bezier(0.11, 0, 0.5, 0)",
    },

    "span:nth-child(11)": {
        animation: "fade-in 0.8s 1.1s forwards cubic-bezier(0.11, 0, 0.5, 0)",
    },

    "span:nth-child(12)": {
        animation: "fade-in 0.8s 1.2s forwards cubic-bezier(0.11, 0, 0.5, 0)",
    },

    "span:nth-child(13)": {
        animation: "fade-in 0.8s 1.3s forwards cubic-bezier(0.11, 0, 0.5, 0)",
    },

    "span:nth-child(14)": {
        animation: "fade-in 0.8s 1.4s forwards cubic-bezier(0.11, 0, 0.5, 0)",
    },

    "span:nth-child(15)": {
        animation: "fade-in 0.8s 1.5s forwards cubic-bezier(0.11, 0, 0.5, 0)",
    },

    "span:nth-child(16)": {
        animation: "fade-in 0.8s 1.6s forwards cubic-bezier(0.11, 0, 0.5, 0)",
    },

    "span:nth-child(17)": {
        animation: "fade-in 0.8s 1.7s forwards cubic-bezier(0.11, 0, 0.5, 0)",
    },
    "span:nth-child(18)": {
        animation: "fade-in 0.8s 1.8s forwards cubic-bezier(0.11, 0, 0.5, 0)",
    },
};

const fadeIn = `
    @-webkit-keyframes fade-in { 
        0% { 
            opacity: 0;
            filter: blur(4px); 
        } 

        100% { 
            opacity: 1; 
            filter: blur(0); 
        } 
    } 
    `;
const scale = `
    @-webkit-keyframes scale {
         0% {
            transform: scale(0) 
        } 100% {
            transform: scale(1) 
        } 
    } `;

function TextAnimation() {
    const style = document.createElement("style");
    style.innerHTML = `${fadeIn} ${scale}`;
    document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(style);

    return (
        <>
            <h1 style={styles.h1}>
                <span style={styles.span}>
                    <span style={styles["span:nth-child(1)"]}>There</span>
                    <span style={styles["span:nth-child(2)"]}>are</span>
                    <span style={styles["span:nth-child(3)"]}>no</span>
                    <span style={styles["span:nth-child(4)"]}>limits</span>
                    <span style={styles["span:nth-child(5)"]}>to</span>
                    <span style={styles["span:nth-child(6)"]}>what</span>
                    <span style={styles["span:nth-child(7)"]}>you</span>
                    <span style={styles["span:nth-child(8)"]}>can</span>
                    <span style={styles["span:nth-child(9)"]}>accomplish,</span>
                    <span style={styles["span:nth-child(10)"]}>except</span>
                    <span style={styles["span:nth-child(11)"]}>the</span>
                    <span style={styles["span:nth-child(12)"]}>limits</span>
                    <span style={styles["span:nth-child(13)"]}>you</span>
                    <span style={styles["span:nth-child(14)"]}>place</span>
                    <span style={styles["span:nth-child(15)"]}>on</span>
                    <span style={styles["span:nth-child(16)"]}>your</span>
                    <span style={styles["span:nth-child(17)"]}>own</span>
                    <span style={styles["span:nth-child(18)"]}>thinking.</span>
                </span>
            </h1>
        </>
    );
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the detailed explanation and code. I tried to render it but it still does not work? :( I added your code to a CodeSandbox:
https://codesandbox.io/s/fade-in-onz6fb?file=/src/App.tsx

Comment: your import of app is incorrect. check this: https://codesandbox.io/s/fade-in-forked-366rfd?file=/src/index.tsx

Comment: I am not sure if manual DOM manipulation in React is good practice, even the React docs say setting HTML from code (eg innerHTML) is risky because it’s easy to inadvertently expose your users to a cross-site scripting (XSS) attack. So, you can set HTML directly from React, but you have to type out dangerouslySetInnerHTML and pass an object with a __html key, to remind yourself that it’s dangerous. Thats from: https://reactjs.org/docs/dom-elements.html

Comment: ok now its working in the sandbox great. @david so how would it look like without innerHTML do you know it?